# LWC navigation to a tab is showing the 'Loading...' even after refreshing multiple times

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

We are trying to open an LWC after clicking 'View All' on a related list LWC. But the tab name is showing 'Loading..' and is not updating even if we refresh it.

[image: Code from initial LWC js file]
[image]

[image]

We have tried checking if there is any fix available for this as we knew this is a known issue. But we couldn't find any direct fix.
Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: @KrisGoncalves -Thank you for your suggestion! But we are trying to achieve it without the use of Aura. The solution #2 you've suggested in the post, will it work just by using the code in LWC?

Comment: The other answer in the question goes over using it in more depth and appeared to work - although not documented as a supported feature.